# $C(X) \otimes A \cong C(X, A)$

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras

The following appears to be something of a folk theorem.

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Then, the C*-algebra $C(X) \otimes A$ is $*$-isomorphic to the C*-algebra $C(X, A)$.

The best reference I have found is a remark consisting of a single sentence in section 5 of Guichardet's notes *Tensor Products of $C^*$-algebras, Part I*.  It seems that the remark implicitly refers to theorem I.4 of Grothendieck's *Résumé des résultats essentiels dans la théorie des produits tensoriels topologiques et des espaces nucléaires*, about the injective tensor product of Banach spaces.

Is there a friendlier, textbook reference out there?

Comment: What _precisely_ do you have in mind for the symbol $\otimes$? (As the answer to this will change the answer to the main question.)

Comment: @Matthew: I mean the minimal tensor product. Of course, any commutative C*-algebra is nuclear.

Comment: You can find a proof in the book "C*-algebras and operator theory" of Murphy, Theorem 6.4.17 therein.

Comment: Andre, if you are allowing yourself to assume nuclearity, doesn't it simply suffice to note that the embedding $C(X)\odot A \to C(X,A)$ equips the former space with a $C^*$-norm?

Comment: @AlexE: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Yemon: I think that establishing density takes a little bit of work.

Comment: @AndreKornell Doesn't a partition of unity do it? I assume that Murphy also needs this, or proves this

Comment: @AndreKornell  Thanks.  I was checking to make sure you didn't mean to consider a _Banach_ space tensor norm (for which see Ryan's book).

Comment: For completeness, it is worth remarking (for this appears nowhere in this thread) that $X$ can also be LOCALLY-compact and the statement is still true. (Otherwise, this would be a pretty limited statement.) This is of course how the statement is given in Theorem 6.4.17 of Murphy's textbook mentioned by @AlexE.

Comment: @PeterHeinig What do you make of [these findings](//hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7906)? Just curious.